# Bash brace expansion with variables for pattern matching

Tags: bash, shell-script, brace-expansion, pattern-matching

I want to loop through all files matching a pattern of the form

```bsh
for file in {prefix1, prefix2, ...}*{postfix1, postfix2, ...}; do
```

How can I programmatically replace `{prefix1, prefix2, ...}` with a list containing these names?
I tried `$prefix*$postfix` with `prefix={prefix1,prefix2,...}` but it doesn't work because the brace expansion is done before the variable expansion.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input files and the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the prefix/suffix patterns don't contain spaces, it's possible to use extended globbing:

```bsh
shopt -s extglob
prefix='@(prefix1|prefix2|prefix3)'
suffix='@(suffix1|suffix2|suffix3)'

echo $prefix*$suffix

for file in $prefix*$suffix; do
    #...
done
```

- Can handle spaces if the variable `IFS` is set appropriately

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use two loops combined with bash arrays, something like this:

```
foo=(one two three)
bar=(four five six)
for f in ${foo[@]}; do 
  for g in ${bar[@]}; do
    echo $f$g
  done
done
```